# Pyspark file creation using pandas udf

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, pyarrow

Having pyspark cluster of two servers 111.123.23.224(master), 111.123.34.234(worker)
Trying to create a temporary pickle file for storing my model after training inside pandas udf function. But the pickle sometime getting created in master server and sometimes in worker server. What should i needs to do so that my pickle file always will create either in master or worker
Here is the below code i m trying

@pandas_udf(schema, functionType=pandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def train_model(df_pandas):

```
model=NearestNeighbours(number_neighbours=5).fit(df_pandas)
file=open("/tmp/model.pkl", "wb")
pickle.dump(model, file)
file.close()

df.groupBY("id").apply(train_model)
```

But with the above the model.pkl file sometimes created inside  111.123.23.224(master) and sometimes in 111.123.34.234(worker). whats the solution so that my model.pkl file will always create either in master or slave

Comment: welcome to SO, Please  provide code sample, so that people will get clear ideea what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Please some one suggest an solution